# How to update XML in Windows Phone 8.0

Tags: c#, xml

Hi :) I have the problem with updating element embeded in XML. I can load XML by code:

```
string _filePath = @"AppSources/UserConfig.xml";
StreamResourceInfo xml = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(_filePath, UriKind.Relative));
var doc = XElement.Load(xml.Stream);
var id = doc.Elements(XName.Get("id")).SingleOrDefault().Value;
```

The problem occurs when i try to update element in this file. I wrote the code:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("ms-ms-resource://" + _filePath, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(uri); //EXCEPTION HERE

using (var stream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
{
    var doc = XDocument.Load(stream);
    var element = doc.Descendants("id").FirstOrDefault();
    element.Value = "1234567";

    doc.Save(stream);
}
```

Problem lies in code line:

```
StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(uri);
```

I get the exception : 'System.ArgumentException'
Additional information from VS: Value does not fall within the expected range.

Please help me in solving the problem. Thank you for patience :).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use xml linq ReplaceWith

```
element.ReplaceWith(new XElement("id", "1234567"));
```